# Function not returning NULL

Tags: c, function, pointers, null, char

I am trying to write a function that returns a pointer copied from the initial function parameter but without withspaces in the beggining and in the end (' ', '\n', '\t').

```
char    *ft_strtrim(char const *s)
{

    unsigned char   *p;
    int             start;
    int             end;
    size_t          index;

    start = 0;
    end = ft_strlen(s) - 1;
    while (s[start] == '\n' || s[start] == '\t' || s[start] == ' ')
        start++;
    while (s[end] == '\n' || s[end] == '\t' || s[end] == ' ')
        end--;
    if (start == 0 && end == ft_strlen(s) - 1)
        return ((char*)s);
    if (end - start < 0)
        return (NULL);
    printf("%d\n", end - start);
    p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (end + 1 - start));
    index = 0;
    while(start <= end)
    {
        p[index] = s[start];
        index++;
        start++;
    }
    p[index] = '\0';
    return (p);
}
```

I want to return NULL when the value of end - start is below 0.Even though in the printf that I used after it to debug the function the value is negative,the function doesn't return NULL and when I compile the code I get segmentation fault.

Comment: If `strlen(s) == 0`, `end == -1`, and `s[end]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: What is the definition of `ft_strlen`, and what input is being given to this function?

Comment: An all space string is also a problem.  `while (s[end] == '\n' || s[end] == '\t' || s[end] == ' ')  end--;` is UB.

Comment: "when I compile the code I get segmentation fault.'  --> Do you mean when you _run_ the code, you get a segmentation fault?

Comment: FYI `(end - start < 0)` can be simplified to `(end < start)`. And the only case where this will happen is if the string is empty or all whitespace. And those are precisely the cases where your code causes undefined behavior, because the `while` loops don't stop when they reach the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: "return NULL when the value of end - start is below 0" is a weak plan.  Better to use `size_t` for indexes and keep everything from going below 0.

Comment: Yes,I want to return NULL when the string is full of whtiespaces. Yes, run, not compile. And the ft_strlen has the same behaviour like the libc function, strlen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what to do when I find the answer to my problem,it's just my second question here.

I changed the condition in

```
if (end < start)
   return (NULL);
```

and used for end and start size_t type and know it works. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: The code before this answer's code `while (s[end] == '\n' || s[end] == '\t' || s[end] == ' ')  end--;` is a significant problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code is effectively doing a *trim* of leading and trailing whitespace, but has UB under a number of conditions, including all spaces.

```
 while (s[end] == '\n' || s[end] == '\t' || s[end] == ' ')
    end--;
```

The above code lead s to undefined behavior as `end < 0` and `s[end]` is undefined behavior.

```
char *strtrim(char const *s) {
  // First first non-white-space
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *s))
    s++;

  if (*s == 0) return NULL;

  // Find last non-WS
  const char *end = s;
  const char *last_non_space = s;
  while (*end) {
    if (!isspace((unsigned char ) *end)) {
      last_non_space = end;
    }
    end++;
  }

  // Allocate
  size_t length = (size_t) (last_non_space - s + 1);
  char *dest = malloc(length + 1);
  if (dest == NULL) return NULL;
  memcpy(dest, s, length);
  dest[length] = '\0';
  return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of `return (p);`, you `return p[index];`? Just a suggestion.